How exactly does OpenGL performs depth calculation for a pixel? Is it the same as rasterization?
I'm looking for information (ideally a quote from a piece of documentation) that explains exactly how OpenGL performs the depth test and whether this value is truly accurate or a numerical approximation. On the Depth Testing page of the Khronos Group, it appears that OpenGL computes the depth information based off the fragments. I believe this question is highly related to the process of rasterization and asking the question on rasterization in general (instead of the depth test) might indirectly answer the depth test question, as each fragment contains depth information.
For the purpose of an example, let's say we have a scene containing geometry (let's assume it is two differently colored triangles on a white background). Suppose now that we want to obtain the color value of a single pixel (let's take the one in the middle), there are multiple approaches with different accuracies.
The most simple approach is to simply select a point at the center of the pixel, if it's the background then return the background color, if we hit a triangle we return the interpolated color from the barycentric coordinates of that triangle. (in the illustration below this would be BLUE). I suspect this is what OpenGL does as explained here, although the article does not go in much detail. This previous question seems to also imply that it's a test of a single point inside the pixel.
A slightly more advanced approach would be to take N samples inside the pixel and then average them. As N grows to infinity, it is the same as computing the sum of surface area integrals (which I describe below). I believe this is what OpenGL calls multisampling (see below)

The correct solution to this problem, in my opinion is to divide the space into region and take a weighted sum of the surface area integrals. The pixel is divided into 4 distinct regions R1, R2, R3, R4. Suppose that the area fractions sum to one. Keeping in mind that along the triangle the color might change, the pixel color should be:

Again, the double integral is due to the fact that within the triangle the value may change (in my example, each triangle has a constant color). For performance reason, I would understand why OpenGL does not compute this.
Going back to my original problem, I want to know if the depth value received from the depth buffer is correctly weighted in this fashion. If not, how exactly is it computed?
From the fragment page:

The size covered by a fragment is related to the pixel area, but rasterization can produce multiple fragments from the same triangle per-pixel, depending on various multisampling parameters and OpenGL state.

It appears that OpenGL is using a single point as mentioned above, possibly at the center of each pixel, unless multisampling parameters are set. In the page on multisampling,

A more general form of antialiasing is the simplest: render at a higher resolution, then compute the final image by averaging the values from the higher resolution image that correspond to each pixel. This is commonly called supersampling.

So if I understand correctly, during the rasterization process with multisampling settings OpenGL creates a higher resolution image, samples the center of each pixel and then average each value to get the final pixel color. Is this process the exact same when the depth is computed?

I would recommend to study OpenGL Specification - Chapter 14 Fixed-Function Primitive Assembly and Rasterization (and of course all followup chapters).  I think most (all) of your questions wil be described there, be it Multisampling (14.3.1) or Polygon rasterization (14.6), especially the section after CullFace. It is important to remember that the values (e.g. color, depth) of the fragment can/will be modified in the different stages of the pipeline.

See also: OpenGL Shading Language - 7.1.5. Fragment Shader Special Variables - gl_FragDepth, gl_FragCoord

The short summary from the other comments is that depth is interpolated in the exact same way any other vertex data is interpolated. Usually by barycentric interpolation at the center of a pixel, or at multiple sampling points inside the pixel when multisampling is enabled. I'm not really sure what you mean by "truly accurate or a numerical approximation": At the sampling points the calculation is as accurate as it can be, but sampling (and thus all rendering to pixels) is a discretization in itself and thus a numerical approximation.

(Not taking into account that meshes itself might already be an approximation of the "real" geometry for anything that isn't flat)

@BDL It is true that a mesh may already be a discrete approximation of a shape, but this is not what I'm concerned about. What I meant by "truly accurate" is essentially taking infinite samples and averaging them (which is equivalent to the double integral). In the specification linked by Erdal, I have my answer
"Another consideration is that accurate calculation
of coverage values may be computationally expensive; consequently we allow a
given GL implementation to approximate true coverage values by using a fast but
not entirely accurate coverage computation." 14.3

This: https://alt.3dcenter.org/artikel/multisampling_anti-aliasing/index_e.php and then
https://alt.3dcenter.org/artikel/multisampling_anti-aliasing/index2_e.php
If you're confused, look a these. In the case of supersampling the values are still incorrect. But as you increase the number of samples, it will eventually converge to the "truly accurate" value

@CedricMartens: I think I kindof understand where you come from. The problem with all these topics is that even when you average with a surface integral, the result is still not "correct". In "reality", there wouldn't be any such interpolation, you would have to use a raster with infinitely small pixels for the result (which is clearly impossible). Whenever you start to discretize into a raster image, you can't reach something like "correct". You can hide more or less of the discretization artifacts, but you never reach "correct".
